# not working Install-Package Microsoft.SqlServer.Types

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, nuget, sql-server-2016

I am trying to deploy an SSRS report that is made on Microsoft SQL Server Builder Report

but I get this error:

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: An unexpected error
>   occurred in Report Processing. --->
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException:
>   An unexpected error occurred in Report Processing. --->
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportingService2010Impl.CreateReportEditSession(String
>   Report, String Parent, Byte[] Definition, String& EditSessionID,
>   Warning[]& Warnings)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2010.CreateReportEditSession(String
>   Report, String Parent, Byte[] Definition, String& EditSessionID,
>   Warning[]& Warnings)

Somewhere I found to install Microsoft.SqlServer.Types. The thing is how do I do this in this program.

It says to install Microsoft.SqlServer.Types. So thinking of other possibilities I tried to install it in Visual Studio because I know you can also make a report through visual studio. I made my project and it also got a mistake so I thought it is the same error. Therefore I tried to run

```
 PM> Install-Package Microsoft.SqlServer.Types
```

> Install-Package : Project 'Default' is not found. At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package Microsoft.SqlServer.Types
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Default:String) [Install-Package], ItemNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetProjectNotFound,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

and again I got a mistake. I have NuGet install

Comment: Download the dll installation file and install it on the server.

Comment: Is your project a database project? Sql project is not supported by nuget now, and you will find out that Manage NuGet packages item is grayed out when you right click on your project.

Comment: I fix it. I tried first to fix it by running the SQLSysClrTypes.msi that you can download through Microsoft® SQL Server® 2014 Feature Pack. (change the year depending on the SQL Server that you have). It should work, but in my case it didn´t so I dowloaded a NuGet package that had the SQLSysClrTypes dll file and put it on my server.

Comment: @Erika Martinez, Glad to know that you have resolved this issue. Could you please transform your comment to answer and mark it which is benefit to other communities who has the same problem? Thanks.